# Why does Oracle SQL*Plus consider two queries executed together on the command line as a syntax error?

Tags: oracle

Consider:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-----------
22-Aug-13 0

SQL> select sysdate from dual; select sysdate from dual;

select sysdate from dual; select sysdate from dual

ORA-00911: invalid character

SQL>
```

Notice that when I execute two queries at once in the command window, it throws the `ORA-00911: invalid character` error which generally indicates syntactic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** a syntax error.

SQL*Plus expects either:

- A **single** SQL command, terminated by either a "`;`" character or a "`/`" on a line by itself.
- A PL/SQL block
- A SQL*Plus command

What you have entered is 2 queries on a single line, which SQL*Plus will send to the RDBMS - Oracle will then try and parse the string sent as a single query and fail because it is not valid SQL.

See the documentation for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039424

Comment: Thanks for including the link to the documentation Phil! That clears it for me.. as when I run multiple queries in a Program window in PLSQL developer, it is intelligent enough to execute each one separately.